# XCode - Most practical way to fix "'autorelease' is unavailable: not available in ARC mode"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using PhoneGap and have two different plug-ins installed.  Plug-in A assumes ARC is active, and Plug-in B does its own memory management.

Since I don't know enough Objective-C to tinker with Plug-in A and make it manage memory itself, the only option I see is to go into Plug-in B and rip out all of the 'autorelease' and 'dealloc' calls, as suggested by Jezen in [error 'autorelease' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363566/im-getting-this-error-autorelease-is-unavailable-not-available-in-automatic-r).

Is there a better option, however?  Can I just have XCode ignore the autorelease and dealloc calls, so I don't have to rip them out of the plug-in?  I'm afraid once I'm finishing ripping up this plug-in, I'll find there are others with the same issue.

Comment: I think you're right Danilo!  I'll give this a try.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Xcode will convert the code to ARC for you.

```
Edit->Refactor->Convert to Objective C ARC...
```

You can preview the changes and Xcode is pretty good about suggestion for fixes, if you have to do any manual changes.